# Youtube downloader script on server end

Tags: php, youtube

I am trying to generate a script which can download youtube videos on the server, I would like the user to provide the video url.

I have searched a lot but, could not make it work. Here's my code.

```
    <?php
// Check download token
if (empty($_GET['mime']) OR empty($_GET['token']))
{
exit('Invalid download token 8{');
}
// Set operation params
$mime = filter_var($_GET['mime']);
$ext  = str_replace(array('/', 'x-'), '', strstr($mime, '/'));
$url  = base64_decode(filter_var($_GET['token']));
$name = urldecode($_GET['title']). '.' .$ext; 
// Fetch and serve
if ($url)
{
// Generate the server headers
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== FALSE)
{/*
    header('Content-Type: "' . $mime . '"');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $name . '"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header('Pragma: public');
*/}
else
{/*
    header('Content-Type: "' . $mime . '"');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $name . '"');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
*/}
$download_video_file = file_put_contents($file_path, fopen($url, 'r'));
exit;
}
// Not found
exit('File not found 8{');
?>
```

But I am still stuck at this, Please help me out.

Comment: You took this from Github, why not ask the person that wrote it?

Answer (score 1):

You will get the code from here

Ref : https://code.google.com/p/php-youtube-downloader/

```
<?php
require_once('youtube.lib.php');
$download_link = get_youtube('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SAQZ0BDXn48'); 

// we will have array here, index 0 is the video ID and index 1 is the download link.
echo $download_link[1];
?>
```

http://php-youtube-downloader.googlecode.com/files/youtube_downloader.zip

GitHub : https://github.com/jeckman/YouTube-Downloader